# Google Analytics Embed API - how to load sign-in button or charts by ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-api, google-analytics-api

we use embed api like on this site - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started

Our page is loading content by ajax, so when we load whole page for first time, sign-in button is correctly displayed, but when we redrawe content by ajax, sign-in button isnt loaded, because google's script has already remembered that it drawed button to element. it's the same as if we called 2x gapi.analytics.auth.authorize(...) second button would not be displayed.

How we can force Google to redrawe sign-in button or charts?

Thank you for your responses